# border radius color em 2 cores

Tags: css, css-border, css-border-radius

Estou tentando colocar 2 cores de bordas com border radius mas não consigo.
A meta é ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu só consigo deixa-la assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código onde .detail é a imagem:

```
.detail {
width: 170px;
height: 170px;
border-radius: 100%;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(75, 87, 100);
border-right: 3px solid rgb(75, 87, 100);
border-left: 3px solid rgb(233, 128, 99);
border-top: 3px solid rgb(233, 128, 99);
padding: 1px;
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o transform: rotate(180deg);

Comment: Não consigo comentar, vou te explicar, a primeira imagem ta com uma div com border-radius: 100%; você aplica a borda de duas cores e dar um transform: rotate(180deg) ou 90deg não lembro.

Comment: Ele inverte a imagem toda de ponta cabeça, não só as bordas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer estilizando uma `<div>` somente para fazer a borda da imagem com o `transform:rotate(deg45)`.
Isso vai rotacionar a `<div>` e a `<img>`. 

Depois na classe da `<img>` é só usar o `transform:rotate(-deg45)` para inverter somente a imagem.

```
.imagem {
   width: 170px;
   height: 170px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   padding: 1px;
   transform:rotate(-deg45)


.borda {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(75, 87, 100);
    border-right: 3px solid rgb(75, 87, 100);
    border-left: 3px solid rgb(233, 128, 99);
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(233, 128, 99);
    transform:rotate(deg45)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Opção 1 - mais próximo do o seu código**

Seu problema é que ao rotacionar o *container* da imagem vc rotaciona tudo que está dentro também.

A minha dica é vc criar essas bordar em um *pseudo elemento*, assim vc pode rotaciona-lo livremente sem interferir no conteúdo da `div`

Veja como fica nesse exemplo

```css
.borda {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.borda img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover
}
.borda::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="borda">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Praia_de_Copacabana_-_Rio_de_Janeiro%2C_Brasil.jpg/250px-Praia_de_Copacabana_-_Rio_de_Janeiro%2C_Brasil.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2 a que eu indicaria**

Usando `linear-gradiente` para fazer a "borda", com essa técnica vc usa um *linear gradiente* com duas metas em 50%, uma com cada cor, a borda branca vc coloca na imagem mesmo. Dessa forma vc nem precisa se preocupar em rotacionar nada e não precisa de pseudo elemento, pois o gradiente já fica alinhado *top to bottom*

Eu achei essa opção mais responsiva, mas fácil de customizar e com menos código.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.borda {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0, red 50%, black 50%);
}
.borda img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="borda">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Praia_de_Copacabana_-_Rio_de_Janeiro%2C_Brasil.jpg/250px-Praia_de_Copacabana_-_Rio_de_Janeiro%2C_Brasil.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Faltou só uma coisa na sua resposta: `linear-gradient(45deg)`, aí você consegue fazer transversal

Comment: @WallaceMaxters uai, mas eu tinha entendido que ele queria reto rss, igual o segundo snippet aqui. A vantagem do gradiente eh que vc gira ele sem girar o conteúdo da div

Comment: É verdade, lendo a pergunta de novo, ele queria deixar reto, não com 45deg